# Can we have some sort of notification system?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, notifications

It seems like the only way to get notified of certain events is to poll the site continuously. And as per the current policy, it seems like there should be at least a 2 minute delay between requests.

So therefore, I am proposing a notification system whereby an app can 'register' for certain events and receive a notification when they occur.

Example:

- an app calls `/0.8/notify/questions?intitle=silverlight`
- the app provides a URL
- whenever a new question with 'silverlight' in the title is posted, the URL specified above is called

Comment: This is what pubsubhubbub is for. I imagine the answer will be no because of complexity. I would rather just have a firehose with every change in it.

Comment: @carson: Complexity? How is that complex?

Comment: Is this related to an iPhone App?
This is the first entry when searching for "iphone push notification", then there is an endless list of interesting apps, but no app actualy implements iPhone push notifications at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Its far too late in the v1 game to add something this complex.

Note that the current policy is that you shouldn't be polling faster than once a minute, not two minutes.

Comment: Couldn't you just defer this 'till v1.1 / 2 / whatever?

Comment: @George - We're not going to commit to ever implementing such a feature.  Not to say that it is **for-sure** *never gonna happen* just that its too early to [status-deferred] this.

Comment: That's okay. It was more of a luxury than a necessity.