# /user/{id}/notifications API call

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I was contemplating adding notifications to my app, Droidstack. I would've liked to be able to add notifications for when new answers are posted to a user's (favorite) questions, when new comments are posted in reply to them or when they're questions / answers are edited by someone else.

Unfortunately, the only ways I could do that are:

- Download all the questions and answers of a user every 15 minutes. These might be in the hundreds, so not a good idea.
- Download only the last 10 items, sorted by activity, and see if they change. If any changes appear, use `/questions/{id}/timeline` to figure out what changed. Not a good idea because that means a separate request for every changed item, plus there's no `/answers/{id}/timeline` (so if an answer changes I can't know what changed -- upvote/downvote, comment, ...).

That's why I propose `/users/{id}/notifications` (or name it any way you want, like `updates`), that would gather all this info under a single API call. This would be very similar to the `/timeline` calls.

Also, none of the data that would be provided by such a call is private. This means that this doesn't have to wait for 2.0. Maybe 1.1? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can synthesize most/all of this call currently (new answers, changes in user rep, and comments directed at user are all accessible in v1.0) however it does take multiple calls.

<strike>We'll revisit this for subsequent API versions.</strike>

As [TheLQ](https://stackapps.com/users/2981/thelq) pointed out, this was added in [v2.1](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/user-notifications).

Comment: Shouldn't this be marked `[status-completed]` since 2.1 supports this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this was already answered here: [Can we have some sort of notification system?](https://stackapps.com/questions/635/can-we-have-some-sort-of-notification-system)

I would like to see this as well but it seems that it isn't going to happen.

Comment: I read that question and it's completely different than mine. I'm not asking for a service that would poll my app whenever something happens. Rather, I'm asking for an API call that I could poll every now and then.