# Are there any webhooks for detecting changes/updates?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have some sort of notification system?](https://stackapps.com/questions/635/can-we-have-some-sort-of-notification-system)

Have you looked at adding any webhooks so applications don't need to continually poll for changes?

Answer (score 1):

It was requested [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/635/can-we-have-some-sort-of-notification-system) and as you can see, the status is **declined**.
What does that mean? It means that it has 0.0001% probability to be implemented.